# How to modify the line as per the newer version of scikit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to change the following lines according to the newer version of scikitlearn since grid_scores_ are replaced  by cv_results_ also, mean_validation_score is replaced by mean_test_score

```
log_likelyhoods_5 = [round(gscore.mean_validation_score) for gscore in model.grid_scores_ if gscore.parameters['learning_decay']==0.5]
log_likelyhoods_7 = [round(gscore.mean_validation_score) for gscore in model.grid_scores_ if gscore.parameters['learning_decay']==0.7]
log_likelyhoods_9 = [round(gscore.mean_validation_score) for gscore in model.grid_scores_ if gscore.parameters['learning_decay']==0.9]
```

I tried:

```
log_likelyhoods_5 = [round(gscore.mean_validation_score) for gscore in model.cv_results_ if gscore.parameters['learning_decay']==0.5]
log_likelyhoods_7 = [round(gscore.mean_validation_score) for gscore in model.cv_results_ if gscore.parameters['learning_decay']==0.7]
log_likelyhoods_9 = [round(gscore.mean_validation_score) for gscore in model.cv_results_ if gscore.parameters['learning_decay']==0.9]
```

shows the error: `no attribute 'parameters'`

What will be the correct line in this case for newer version of scikitlearn?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `params` key of `cv_results_` in [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn-model-selection-gridsearchcv):

> The key `params` is used to store a list of parameter settings dicts for all the parameter candidates.

So you should use `gscore.params['learning_decay']`

Comment: @AtomStore did this answer your question? If yes, please accept it and consider upvoting. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)